# Alternative to lookbehind in js

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to use javascript to do text replacements for variables with the follow format @variable (yes I know it is bad practice, but sadly it's data from an external system so I cannot change it).

The problem is that I need to ensure that it also works if there are mail addresses in the text.
Therefor it needs to match @variable but not test@example.com. If it was in another language I would simply use something like, but js does not support lookbehind.

```
text.replace(/(?<!\w)@[\w]+/g, replacement);
```

'@var' matches @var

'@var bar' matches @var

'bar@var' does not match

'bar2@var' does not match

Any javascript way of doing this using regex?

Here is an example of the expected result using negative lookbehind
https://regex101.com/r/orCEGE/1

Comment: Based on what _exactly_ do you not want to replace `test@variable.com`? That there is text before the @, without any whitespace? Based on that there is a “suffix” of the form `.xyz`? Or what exactly are your criteria for replace or don’t replace here?

Comment: My though is that @ should not be preceded by either a letter or a number. Everything else is valid and should result in a match/replacement

Comment: You could simply try and match one of those characters before the `@variable`, grouped, and then insert whatever that match was back in with `$1` - `"foo @variable baz".replace(/([^0-9a-z])@variable/, '$1XXX')` And then, to take into account that the variable might be at the very beginning of the text with nothing before it, throw in an alternation with `^` - `"@variable baz".replace(/(^|[^0-9a-z])@variable/, '$1XXX')`

Comment: Close but sadly sometimes the variable is in a sentence and this would also replace the preceding space :)

Comment: What do you mean by in a sentence, something different than my example `foo @variable baz`? For that it works fine, because the space is caught by `([^0-9a-z])`, and re-inserted into the replacement via `$1` …

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what exactly you want to replace, but here's a fairly generic method:

```js
const text = "@A foo@bar@baz @var@asdf.@Z";

const result = text.replace(/@(\w+)/g,
  (m0, m1, pos, str) => {
    if (pos > 0 && /\w/.test(str.charAt(pos-1))) {
      return m0;
    }
    return "{replacement for " + m1 + "}";
  }
);

console.log(result);
```

The replacement function gets not just the matched parts of the string, but also the position where the match occurred. This match position can be used to make further decisions (e.g. whether the matched string should be returned unchanged (as in `return m0;`)).